# ContentNegotiatingViewResolver MediaTypes Error after Upgrading to Spring 4.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a dispatcher-servlet.xml file that has a `Bean` like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:defaultContentType="text/html">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean id="localBasedViewResolver" class="com.company.web.i18n.LocaleBasedViewResolver"
                  p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
                  p:prefix="${views.prefix}"
                  p:suffix="${views.suffix}"
                  p:cacheUnresolved="false"
                  p:exposedContextBeanNames="webProperties"
                  p:order="1"
                  />
            <bean id="viewResolver"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
                  p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
                  p:prefix="${views.prefix}"
                  p:suffix="${views.suffix}"
                  p:cacheUnresolved="false"
                  p:exposedContextBeanNames="webProperties"
                  p:order="2"
                  />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After upgrading to Spring 4.2 I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mediaTypes' of bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver]: Bean property 'mediaTypes' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

This worked before the upgrade, so any help on how to fix would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Spring 4.2 ContentNegotiatingViewResolver now delegates content negotiation to a ContentNegotiationManager. Define a ContentNegotiationManager bean in your application context and set it on your view resolver as follows

```
 <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"  class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />

        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
               <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
           </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Then update your view resolver as follows

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean id="localBasedViewResolver" class="com.company.web.i18n.LocaleBasedViewResolver"
                  p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
                  p:prefix="${views.prefix}"
                  p:suffix="${views.suffix}"
                  p:cacheUnresolved="false"
                  p:exposedContextBeanNames="webProperties"
                  p:order="1"
                  />
            <bean id="viewResolver"
                  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
                  p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
                  p:prefix="${views.prefix}"
                  p:suffix="${views.suffix}"
                  p:cacheUnresolved="false"
                  p:exposedContextBeanNames="webProperties"
                  p:order="2"
                  />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Awesome! I think we are almost there. It is still complaining about the p:defaultContentType="text/html". Does that also go in the ContentNegotiationManager or is that a separate question? If possible I would like to get that resolved here in case that will also help the next person who comes here.

Comment: defaultContentType should be in the ContentNegotiationManager as indicated above  <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />. Change it to suit your needs