# spring mvc can't access .html files

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I searched all over the site and nothing suggested worked!
I'm tryng to make a spring-mvc and angularJS application; This is my project structure:

```
angularState
-src/main/java/it.controller.DefaultController.java
-src/main/webapp
--index.jsp
--WEB-INF
---dispatcher-servlet.xml
---web.xml
---static
----default.html
```

so in my web.xml I have:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

in the dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.controller"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/static/" mapping="/static/**" />
```

in the index.jsp:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("default"); %>
```

then in the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/default")
public class DefaultController {
public String showDefault(){
    return "/static/default.html";
}
}
```

I've always used jsp and everything was fine; now I've tried every single question of the site:
I've tried
-mvc:default-servlet-handler
-InternalResourceViewResolver with prefix "/WEB-INF/static" and suffix ".html" or even suffix void
-InternalResourceViewResolver void and the controller method returning "/WEB-INF/static/default.html"
NOTHING!
nothing showed the default.html. why that .html file is so complicated!

Comment: How is your view resolved configured? Provide this part of context xml

Comment: Try one thing, change `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>` and append app in URL as well.. Let me know if helps.

Comment: Have you tried to change your @RequestMapping? like `@RequestMapping(value="/default")`

Comment: @Andremoniy it is not configured at all because .html files don't need to pass through servlet, they're static resources, so I used
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/static/" mapping="/static/**" />
I tried using:
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/static/" />
 <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
 </bean>
but nothing.
Mike: tried but nothing(it's the same thing)
NewUser: same error: No mapping found....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will google, here the answer.
the problem was pretty simple: All I was wrong was the controller method; the original controller method was:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/default")
public class DefaultController {
    public String showDefault(){
        return "/static/default.html";
    }
}
```

the correct version must be:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/default")
public class DefaultController {
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showDefault(){
        return "/static/default.html";
    }
}
```

because every page must have a GET access, more than all, the homepage!
Because of that missing @RequestMapping on the method, every config I tried gave me errors on the .html files. As I sayd, .html files only needs the

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/static/" mapping="/static/**" />
```

to be configured because they're static resources and they don't need the help of the servlet. Hope this will help someone, thanks to everyone who tried.

Answer (score 1):

This is because normally *.jsp style uri patterns are handled by the servlet container and in your case *.html is not being handled by the container and instead the path is being delegated to Spring MVC which does not know how to render these extensions
As a quick fix you can try below code in conf/web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or

Content negotiating view resolver can also be used in place of InternalResourceViewResolver(I Guess you might be using this) which return a suitable view based on file extension declared in “mediaTypes” property)
Example

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
          <property name="order" value="1" />
          <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
               <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            </map>
          </property>
```

Comment: your first solution gives me "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/angularState/default] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'"
your second solution gave me the error on the mediaTypes' setter, so I adjusted it using the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304055/contentnegotiatingviewresolver-mediatypes-error-after-upgrading-to-spring-4-2
and then it gave me the same error of the first try.

Comment: Your error suggests that DispatcherServlet is trying to process the request for .html pages also.Below needs to be changed <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>dispatcher</servlet>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> to  <url-pattern>/.controllers</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>.Try calling controllers with different extension like .controllers and update the servlet mapping